# URLSessionDataDelegate methods not being called

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm starting a download session in a view controller:

```swift
class MyController: UIViewController {
  func startDownload(withURL url: URL) {
    downloadSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
                                      delegate: self,
                                 delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    downloadTask = downloadSession.dataTask(with: url)
    downloadTask.resume()
  }
}
```

The delegate methods are defined in an extension:

```
extension MyController: URLSessionDelegate {
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                   dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, 
            didReceive data: Data) {
     ...
  }

  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                       task: URLSessionTask, 
    didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
     ... 
  }
}
```

Why are these delegate methods never called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only declare conformance to `URLSessionDelegate` in your extension. If you declare conformance to `URLSessionDataDelegate` instead, your delegate methods will be called.